# getting server 500 error with nusoap

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap, nusoap

i want to use nusoap package to working with some webservices. according to documentation of nusoap, we first have to include nusoap.php to our php script and then write other codes...

http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapintro.htm

but when i include nusoap.php to my code like this:

```
require_once('nusoap.php');
```

i get an server 500 error that says(IE 10):

```
 Most likely causes:
    •The website is under maintenance.
    •The website has a programming error.
```

but i dont understand what is the caus of it...  i enabled error_reporting in php.ini but it doestnt show any error, it says server 500 error!!
whats's the problrm? how i can know more about the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the exact same problem. This was the first webservice I created and I didn't know anything about, so the reason for my problem was my own foolishness.

This was what it looked like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
$namespace = "http://www.mywebsite.com/services";

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("TestService");
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

$server->register('TestFunction', array('test'=>'xsd:string'), array('return'=>'xsd:string'), $namespace, false, 'rpc', 'encoded', 'Function for evaluation of SOAP');

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

So you see, i just forgot to define the function..

Following works:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
$namespace = "http://www.mywebsite.com/services";

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("TestService");
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

$server->register('TestFunction', array('test'=>'xsd:string'), array('return'=>'xsd:string'), $namespace, false, 'rpc', 'encoded', 'Function for evaluation of SOAP');

function TestFunction($test) {
    return "Response: ".$test;
}

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

I hope I could help you.